# enable radio buttons in 2nd column based on content selected in first column

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a JSON which I am rendering in a table format with content as radio buttons. The first two items of second column should be enabled only if first item of first column is enabled and so on in the same way.
Eg:- Doe,Anna should be enabled in 2nd column if John in selected.Rest all should be disabled
Could anyone help me with this

```
HTML
    <div class="row" id="inputTableSector">
      <table id="inputTable" class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td>first name</td>
            <td>last name</td>
            <td>manager</td>
            <td>domain</td>
            <td>Alpha</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let employee of employees;">
            <td><input type="radio" name="firstName" [value]="employee.firstName" [(ngModel)]="currentFirstName"><span>{{employee?.firstName}}</span></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="lastName" [value]="employee.lastName" [(ngModel)]="currentLastName"><span>{{employee?.lastName}}</span></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="manager" [value]="employee.manager" [(ngModel)]="currentManager"><span>{{employee?.manager}}</span></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="domain" [value]="employee.domain" [(ngModel)]="currentDomain"><span>{{employee?.domain}}</span></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="alpha" [value]="employee.alpha" [(ngModel)]="currentAlpha"><span>{{employee?.alpha}}</span></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

TYPESCRIPT
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
      protected employees: any;
      protected currentLastName: string;
      protected currentFirstName: string;
      protected currentManager: string;
      protected currentDomain: string;
      protected currentAlpha: string;
     ngOnInit() {
        // const employeesJSON = this.http.get("https://api.myjson.com/bins/tshu8").pipe(map(res => res.json()));
        // this.employees = JSON.parse(employeesJSON);
        this.http.get("https://api.myjson.com/bins/tbzpc").subscribe( 
        response => {this.employees=response}
        );
      }

    JSON
    [{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe","manager":"paul","domain":"digital"},{"firstName":"Anna","lastName":"Smith","manager":"Abraham","domain":"mechanics"},{"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones","manager":"Jonathan","domain":"physics"},{"firstName":"Watson","lastName":"carter","manager":"Bravo","domain":"chemistry"},{"firstName":"","lastName":"Daniel","manager":"Pollock","domain":"biology"},{"firstName":"","lastName":"Smith","manager":"Tait","domain":"analogy"},{"firstName":"","lastName":"Queen","manager":"Mcgrath","domain":"mathematics"},{"firstName":"","lastName":"Elizebeth","manager":"Waugh","domain":"english"}]
```

Comment: Doe and Smith should be enabled right , first wo items of second column?

Comment: created stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b8rcrn?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Please consider this JSON as reference
https://api.myjson.com/bins/qjq7o

When we select John,Doe and Smith should be enabled.When we select Anna,Jones and carter should be enabled and so on.

Comment: is first column always enabled??

Comment: yes the first column is always enabled

Answer (score 0):

use index in loop and name change by index

```
<tr *ngFor="let employee of employees; let i = index;">
  <td><input type="radio" name="firstName-{{i}}" [value]="employee.firstName" [(ngModel)]="currentFirstName"><span>{{employee?.firstName}}</span></td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="lastName-{{i}}" [value]="employee.lastName" [(ngModel)]="currentLastName"><span>{{employee?.lastName}}</span></td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="manager-{{i}}" [value]="employee.manager" [(ngModel)]="currentManager"><span>{{employee?.manager}}</span></td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="domain-{{i}}" [value]="employee.domain" [(ngModel)]="currentDomain"><span>{{employee?.domain}}</span></td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="alpha-{{i}}" [value]="employee.alpha" [(ngModel)]="currentAlpha"><span>{{employee?.alpha}}</span></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Actually in  a column only one item needs to be selected at a time,if I am adding "i" in name, it is not working as expected. Could you please suggest some other way

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below option

1. Create array to store indexes of radios to be enabled

   enableArr = [];
2. Use change event for first column and push indexes to enableArr based on selection of first column

   enableColumn(e, i){
             this.enableArr.indexOf(i) === -1 ? this.enableArr.push(i,i+1) : this.enableArr.push(i+1,i+2)
         }
3. Use [disabled] property to enable second column based on enableArr

   isDisabled(val){
           return val >= 0? this.enableArr.indexOf(val) === -1 : true;
         }

working code sample - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7gguqf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts